# write.table R failing

Tags: r, write.table

I'm running a small script, it works ok, but whenever I try to write the dataframe, the number of rows that I get as output (32933) is different from the number of rows that I'm expecting (18285).

```
datsort <- read.table("/home/.../vep_data_sorted.csv", header = T, sep="\t", fill = T)
dim(datsort)
#[1] 97059    47

datsort <- datsort[which(datsort$variation_type == "SNV"),]
dim(datsort)
#[1] 40954    47

gmaf <- as.numeric(as.character(datsort$GMAF_freq))
exac <- as.numeric(as.character(datsort$ExAC))

gmaf[which(is.na(gmaf) == T)] <- 0
exac[which(is.na(exac) == T)] <- 0

x <- which(gmaf < 1)
y <- which(exac < 1)

int <- intersect(x,y)
length(int)
#[1] 18285

datsort <- datsort[int,]
dim(datsort)
#[1] 18285    47

write.table(datsort, "/home/.../vep_data_sorted_1per.csv", sep="\t", quote = F, row.names = F)
```

Then I check the the number of lines and columns

```
#Rows    
wc -l vep_data_sorted_1per.csv
32933 vep_data_sorted_1per.csv
#Column
awk -F '\t' '{print NF}' vep_data_sorted_1per.csv | sort -nu | tail -n 1
47
```

Any suggestion of what I'm missing?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to write part of you data.frame? And also is there any particular reason to use '\t' as separator instead of ';' or ','?

Comment: No. I use the tab because the next software needs a tab delimited file.

Comment: You should be looking for unmatched single or double quotes. You could also try reading the file that you created back in with `read.delim`.

Comment: Building on 42's comment, you could try and export a data frame without quotes and using an uncommon character for a delimiter like a `|` or `¦` to confirm unmatched quotes.

Comment: I've added a quote = "\"" to the initia read.table and it seems ok. Not sure why but seems to go ok.